# Android Create Json Object String From Data

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to create Json String like this from available data,

Json String:

```
{
  "1": {
    "attendance_user_status": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "attendance_user_status": 0
  },
  "3": {
    "attendance_user_status": 1
  },
  "4": {
    "attendance_user_status": 1
  },
  "5": {
    "attendance_user_status": 1
  },
  "6": {
    "attendance_user_status": 0
  },
  "7": {
    "attendance_user_status": 1
  }, ...
}
```

I wrote this java code..

```
public String jsonCreator(ArrayList<Attendance> attendanceArrayList) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0;i<attendanceArrayList.size();i++){
        JSONObject objId = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject objAtt = new JSONObject();
        objAtt.put("attendance_user_status",attendanceArrayList.get(i).getValue());

        objId.put(attendanceArrayList.get(i).getId(),objAtt);
        jsonArray.put(objId);
    }
    object.put("user",jsonArray);

    return object.toString();
}
```

But using this code I'm getting this array, Not as I required.

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "1": {
        "attendance_user_status": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "2": {
        "attendance_user_status": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "3": {
        "attendance_user_status": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "4": {
        "attendance_user_status": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append json object but not by json array.

Answer (score 0):

You never initilize `json` any other than `String json = "";`, so an empty string will be returned.

You have to get the string from your json object and set it to `json`.
Do the following at the end of your method:

```
 json = objId.toString();
 return json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public String jsonCreator(ArrayList<Attendance> attendanceArrayList) throws JSONException {
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   for(int i = 0;i<attendanceArrayList.size();i++){
       JSONObject objId = new JSONObject();

       JSONObject objAtt = new JSONObject();
       objAtt.put("attendance_user_status",attendanceArrayList.get(i).getValue());

       objId.put(attendanceArrayList.get(i).getId(),objAtt);
       jsonArray.put(objId);
   }

   return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

Comment: how can you get json of array of `JSONObject` without `JSONArray`?